# How to create same location to point different proxy server

Tags: nginx

I have configured the Load Balancer(Nginx) for ignition. I have created two upstream(ignapp & ignProdapp) server. For ignapp upstream it is working fine. I need to configure the below code for upstream server(ignProdapp) in the same configuration file how to do this. Below is the sample configuration for the server ignapp. Can you please help me how to configure the below settings for another upstream server. Below is the config setting for ignapp same way I need to do it for creating location ~ /data/, location ~ /system/ , location ~ /res/ , location ~ /idp/, location ~ /.well-known/ for ignappPro Upstream server .

```
Upstream ignapp{
ip_hash;
server 10.10.10.11:8088;
}
upstream ignappPro {
ip_hash;
server 10.10.10.12:8088;
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.abdul.com;
location ~ /data/ {
proxy_pass http://ignapp/data/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location ~ /system/ {
proxy_pass http://ignapp/system/;
tp_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location ~ /res/ {
proxy_pass http://ignapp/res/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location ~ /idp/ {
proxy_pass http://ignapp/idp/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location ~ /.well-known/ {
proxy_pass http://ignapp/.well-known/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
# Here we are setting the protocol type, address, port, and uri (optional) that will be the destination of our proxied server:
location / {
proxy_pass http://ignapp/data/perspective/client/demo/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```